# Re-import a library in Chez Scheme

Tags: chez-scheme

In Chez, how do I reload (re-import) a library into the REPL that I've already imported once?

The [Chez Scheme User's Guide](https://scheme.com/csug8/use.html#./use:h4) says:

> When defined directly in the REPL or loaded explicitly from a file, a library form can be used to redefine an existing library, but `import` never reloads a library once it has been defined.

`load` and `load-library` don't seem to re-import either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence works for me in Chez v9.5:

```
> (import (mylib))
;; make some changes to mylib
> (load "src/mylib.scm")
> (import (mylib))
```